# ¿como normalizar datos de una tabla SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla de SQL con varios miles de registros telefonicos, algunos comienzan por 34, y otros por 9 o 6.

¿Como puedo normalizar la tabla para quitar el 34 inicial a los registros?

Muchas gracias

---

Detalles de la consulta:

```
SELECT  *
  FROM [BBDD_ESP_TLMARK].[dbo].[leads_1]
SELECT  *
  FROM [BBDD_ESP_TLMARK].[dbo].[leads_2]
SELECT  *
  FROM [BBDD_ESP_TLMARK].[dbo].[leads_3]


Select * from [dbo].[leads_1]
union
Select * from [dbo].[leads_2]
union
Select *  from [dbo].[leads_3]
Order by Telefono
```

Dentro de esta unión me aparece un listado de teléfonos con 7K registros, algunos no son validos y otros tienen el prefijo 34, me gustaría quitarles el prefijo 34 y eliminar los no validos, es decir, lo que tengan más o menos de 9 dígitos

Comment: Si pudieses añadir un script de creacion del formato de la tabla nos harías más fácil contestarte, en plan `CREATE TABLE nombre` para ver mas o menos con que estás trabajando. Además, cuando quieres modificar esa tabla? Cada vez que se introduzca un registro nuevo o todos los valores a la vez de una sola vez?

Comment: Select * from [dbo].[Leads1]
union
Select * from [dbo].[leads2]
union
Select *  from [dbo].[leads3]
Order by Telefono

Comment: Dentro de esta unión me aparece un listado de teléfonos con 7K registros, alguno sno son validos y otros tienen el prefijo 34, me gustaría quitarles el prefijo 34 y eliminar los no validos, es decir, lo que tengan más o menos de 9 dígitos

Comment: Por favor pon la estructura de tu tabla para poderte ayudar

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar [SUBSTRING](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Por ejemplo, quiero quitar el 34 (los dos primeros dígitos):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('34123456789',3,9)

Resultado: 123456789
```

Para contar utiliza la función [LEN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Por ejemplo, quiero contar cuantos caracteres tiene el número telefónico:

```
SELECT LEN('34123456789')
    
Resultado: 11
```